# "[ - abc=10 ]" vs "[ – abc = 10 ]"

Tags: test

How are they different?

I am using the `[` command.  I know we need a space after `[` and before `]`, and that the `test` command is equivalent.  But I can't find any information about the difference between the expressions

- `[ abc=10 ]` and
- `[ abc = 10 ]`

Comment: What are you actually asking? (Please use the `{}` code button to highlight code that illustrates your question.)

Comment: Is that an en dash? And not even an ASCII hyphen? Is that the name of some command or what is it supposed to be?

Comment: For starters, `– abc=10` is two words and `– abc = 10` is four words. If passed to a command, the former results in two arguments and the latter results in four arguments.

Comment: I believe that it’s clear what the question is asking  —  but isn’t this a duplicate of, like, 42 other questions?

Answer (score 2):

`abc=10` will set the variable `abc` equal to `10`.

`abc = 10` will execute `abc` with parameters `=` and `10`.

Comment: Not within `[...]`, which is what I believe the user means, judging from the title.

Comment: To be fair,  there were no brackets in the title  when this answer was posted.